# WPF Validation with Entlib 5.0 on non text properties

Tags: c#, binding, enterprise-library

I am trying to validate user input in WPF with Entlib 5.0. I want to check if value in textbox is a number.

My model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
    public double Country { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
         <Binding Path="Country" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  >
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                  <vab:ValidatorRule ValidationSpecificationSource="All" SourceType="{x:Type bl:Customer}" SourcePropertyName="Country"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

When I am setting the text to texbox Validation.HasError is set to false.

Any ideas how I can validate this situation.

Comment: Quick workaround for me is to expose value as string property and parse string but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Binding should looks like this:

```
<Binding Path="Country" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
   <Binding.ValidationRules>
       <vab:ValidatorRule ValidationSpecificationSource="All" SourceType="{x:Type bl:Customer}" SourcePropertyName="Country"/>
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```